# Entropy, enthalpy, and energy through rapid mitosis

Tags: super-powers, energy, biochemistry, mathematics, thermodynamics

So I'm pretty new to chemistry and all this, but my world involves superpowers, which of course involves immense energy to have the characters use these powers. However, I want to stay consistent with the laws of thermodynamics, so with that said, here's a specif example.

I have a character who can transform himself into dinosaurs near instantaneously (ideally). We know to do this he would have to drastically increase his mass if he wanted to transform into a T. Rex.

So let's do some math here. We know that E=mc<sup>2</sup> and the mass of the average adult human male is 200 lbs and the mass of a Tyrannosaurus is 18000 lbs. Changing mass like this would result in a 8900% increase. This also means the maximum amount of energy that can be stored in this body is 8153506981500.4 MJ and the maximum amount that can be stored in a T. Rex's body is 7.3381562833504E+14 MJ.

But here's where things get even more complicated. Because changing into something this large this fast would require more energy than the human body can contain, he would need an extra power source (which I have already implemented). So I assume this would mean, he actually has more energy per cubic inch of his body, very compact, like a black hole.

So here's my ultimate question: **can we use Gibb's free energy equation to find out how fast the chemical reactions would be for a man to transform into a T. Rex, and if so, what is the equation for it? If we can't use the equation, what can we do to discover how fast this transformation could be?** Please feel free to point out any scientific inaccuracies I have presented and call me out on them.

Comment: Chemical reactions don't happen that fast. Not to mention that the generation of matter through energy isn't  a chemical reaction. If you're going to have superpowers, there's really no need to obey the laws of thermodynamics.

Comment: Not an asnwer to the question as asked, but: If you realy want to put a sciency gloss on it, why not have them make-up the difference by having the power of being a dark-matter magnet and able to convert it into normal matter in their body - then presumably reverse the process to shrink again.

Comment: It takes an Axolotl close to 2 months to regrow a limb or body part, A blue whale calf may be the fastest growing creature but that takes tonnes of food each day to be consumed by the mother.

Comment: Mass **is** energy, and energy **is** mass. The energy corresponding to the mass of a *T. rex* **is** the mass of a *T. rex*. There is no such thing as massless energy. Your handwaved energy source **must** weigh exactly as much as a *T. rex*.

Comment: @AlexP not all energy contains mass, for instance, photons facilitate the electromagnetic interaction, but are massless meaning they have no rest mass. In GR, photons appear to interact with gravity but only as a consequence of gravity being a geometric construct. This is the problem of incompatibility between quantum theory and GR because forces are seen the result of interactions expressed mathematically as fields and mediated by particles, hence the postulated graviton.

Comment: @user110866: Photons are most definitely *not* massless. They do not have a rest mass, that's true, but we don't care because they are never at rest anyway. Real photons, travelling at the speed of light, have mass equal to the energy they carry, that is, $h \nu$. Really, mass and energy are two words for the same thing.

Comment: @AlexP Mass is much more than just energy, it is a form of energy which carries with it restrictions on the ways in which energy is allowed to interact. In a classical sense, mass carries information on how the object accelerates in the presence of forces, the massless property of photons is the reason they are never at rest and always propagating at the speed of light in free space (they cannot accelerate or decelerate, they just interact and doing so they transmit their energy).

Comment: @AlexP Also, mass carries with it Kinetic Energy, using this definition results in a failure to describe the photon accurately, $h\nu$ is the total energy of a photon in terms of the frequency of the electric and magnetic waves, however, half this energy is stored in the magnetic component and half in the electric component. So this violates the Conservation of energy if $E_{T} = KE+PE = (0.5) h \nu c^2 + h \nu > h\nu$ and the theory breaks down

Comment: @user110866: You are confused. Energy *does not* "interact" with anything, because it is not a "something" which can interact. Energy is an attribute of a physical system, a state function. You cannot have energy in the abstract; energy is always the energy of some physical system. It is the physical system which interacts (or doesn't interact) with other physical systems. In such interactions, energy may be exchanged between physical system, may change forms, etc.

Comment: @AlexP Perhaps I am confused as to how you are defining things like "Energy". In modern physics, energy is a mathematical abstraction in the sense that we cannot directly observe it, it is a mathematical quantity we can readily infer from measurable observables and which always obeys certain rules, hence its usefulness. In the standard model, Energy itself is not a state function because it is independent of equilibrium conditions. Energy is a conserved quantity arising from time translation symmetry. The part (mass for instance) should not be confused for the whole (energy itself)

Comment: @AlexP As regards interaction, I was expressing the photon as a form of energy because it carries with it the electromagnetic interaction without mass. If you are merely saying that mass is just the property of physicality along with energy, and thus using one as a synonym for the other, this is purely a matter of semantics...

Comment: Well mass is energy that is able to provide resistence. Not any energy is mass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gibbs' free energy is the amount of reversible energy that an isobaric and isothermic system can perform through the exerting of work. Since such a processes would not be reversible, isobaric or isothermic, using Gibbs' free energy in this calculation would be meaningless.

Gibbs' free energy is not restricted to just chemical reactions, for example it has use in particle interactions, however, the above restrictions still apply.

To clear up some confusion about mass-energy, mass is a form in which energy may be stored, energy itself is not mass. Mass in a classical sense, relates to the acceleration which an object experiences under the influence of a given force. We say that mass is a form of energy because it must be included when discussing energy transfer in physical interactions. Mass does not represent the amount of energy that may be stored in an object, but rather the **total energy** we must take into account for an object which is **at rest** in our frame of reference. This is the meaning of E = M$c^2$, where M is the rest Mass of the object and thus E is called the rest energy of the object.

The total energy of an object changes relative to us once we move relative to it, and this is described using a quantity called the invariant energy. Mass-energy is therefore a mathematical construct used to describe a physical situation. The physical link is much more nuanced, because most mass in an object comes from the binding-energy of the potentials holding the object together. As @Slarty pointed out, the strong nuclear and electromagnetic interactions are the main forces at play here (gravity is too weak to be of any significance to a human or dinosaur sized mass). So to answer the question, *which formula should be most taken into consideration?*, the most pressing would be the conservation of energy. As you pointed out, the mass of a dinosaur is much greater than that of a human, so the most simplistic way to add this energy would be to add the required mass. But this doesn't solve the problem of turning a human into a dinosaur because a lot of additional energy is needed to rearrange the atoms of the additional objects added to human to turn the human into a dinosaur.

A particularly common way of doing this in sci-fi is to have a biological entity that can absorb biological material and re purpose it to take on a new shape and function. Since biological components are more likely to be compatible when forming a new organism than non-organic material and thus require the minimum energy in the conversion process, this seems like the best way to go. Thus your super human would be most efficient and realistic by absorbing other organisms and using them to build a dinosaur body, this would be much easier than modifying mass with gravity (black-hole for instance) and building a new body atom by atom through some exotic handwavium.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer the question, no you cannot use the Gibbs free energy equation to meaningfully do this calculation because it is not primarily a chemical reaction.

Converting some super compressed form of matter into ordinary matter would involve some form of unknown physics that allowed the electromagnetic force and the strong nuclear force to be manipulated so as to allow atoms to be compressed far beyond normal. The mechanism for this is entirely unclear.

Any manipulation of the strong nuclear force would require energies many orders of magnitude greater than those involved in chemical reactions. The strong nuclear force is a completely different beast to the electromagnetic force uses different equations and marches to the beat of a different drum.